# How to give FontSize to tableview in Titanium framework for iphone?

Tags: titanium, tableview

I am creating titanium framework application for tableview,I am able to load/show data into the table.But how to give FONTSIZE, so i can manage the text size......

please help me out using any useful link or any example....

Thanks for help!!!

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do a custom label then `row.add(label)`.

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/table_view_layout_2.js

Use the above example and you can build your rows to look however you need them.